# Page transition not work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I'm trying to implement a page transition with angularjs "ngAnimate".

When the page loads the animation is from the bottom to top, the css animation it works properly on the first page load.

But when change the page by pressing the "Go to ..." or "Back" located at the bottom of page, the animation does not work properly.

These are the files: [Plunker][1]

Thanks.

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/j7r3s33Y3GcTyH2Fop9K?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular page no longer considers the top of the window but considers scroll the page.

The solution is to add this in the main controller:

```
// RESET NG-VIEW TOP POSITION
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```